# What is the remainder when $a$ is divided by 6?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

An integer $a$ leaves the same remainder when divided by $3$ and $12$, it also leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$, what is the remainder when $a$ is divided by 6?

Here's my attempt, would be glad if someone can confirm whether if I'm right in my arguments.

We are told that $a \equiv r \mod 3$ and $a \equiv r \mod 12$.

We know that $a \equiv r \mod 12 \iff a \equiv r \mod 3$ and $a \equiv r \mod 4$. Since we are told that $a$ leaves a remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$, then $a \equiv 2 \mod 4$. So by the iff statement, we have $a \equiv 2 \mod 12$. But, we also know that  $a \equiv r \mod 12 \iff a \equiv r \mod 2$ and $a \equiv r \mod 6$, so $a \equiv 2 \mod 6$.

EDIT: I also want to confirm, is the statement $a \equiv b \mod (mn) \iff a \equiv b \mod m$ and $a \equiv b \mod n$ only true for different $m$ and $n$? For example, obviously $a \equiv 2 \mod (2*2) \iff a \equiv 2 \mod 2$ is false.

EDIT 2: After the discussion in the comments that $a \equiv b \mod (mn) \iff a \equiv b \mod m$ and $a \equiv b \mod n$ only when $gcd(m,n)=1$, I realize the last step of my proof isn't correct, since I said "$a \equiv r \mod 12 \iff a \equiv r \mod 2$ and $a \equiv r \mod 6$", but clearly $gcd(2,6)=2 \neq 1$, how do I complete the proof then?

Comment: I would perhaps be careful using modular notation when writing this down... There is nothing in the modular notation saying that when $a \equiv r \pmod 3$, then $0\leq r < 3$. Notational nitpicking aside, I think the proof itself is fine.

Comment: I also agree that the proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks, just edited my question with related query. Would appreciate clarification.

Comment: For the question in your EDIT you need gcd(m,n)=1 I think.

Comment: @coffeemath Ah, thanks, I can see why that's the case. So that means for $m$ and $n$ that are not coprime, then we have the implication $a \equiv b \mod m$ and $a \equiv b \mod n$ $\implies$ $a \equiv b \mod lcm(m,n)$, right?

Comment: user3184733 I think you're right sbout the more general version (implication only one way, congruence mod lcm(m,n)). It should be easy to show that if true... [Hmm maby its iff, using lcm(m,n) ..]

Comment: I second the notation critique. You should instead write $\ a\bmod 3 = r = a\bmod 12.\,$  Confusing operational vs relational $\rm mod$  is one of the biggest sources of errors made by beginners in elementary number theory. So, unlike the above author, I would not call such critiques "nitpicking" since they often reflect fundamental conceptual misunderstandings.

Comment: for your edit, you need either $\,\gcd(m,n) = 1\,$ or, more generally, replace $\,mn\,$ by $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n).\,$ See the [constant case of CRT.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

Comment: On the difference between $\rm mod$ as a binary operator vs. ternary relation (congruence) see e.g.  [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) or [Arturo Magidin's answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121054/242).