# modular arithmetic addition rule

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image: consider the rule]

Consider this addition rule in modular arithmetic:
If I take n=10, a=3, b=7

Then, on the left hand side, we have (3)mod10 + (7)mod10= 3 + 7 = 10

On the right hand side, we have 10 mod10, which is zero.

LHS is therefore not equal to RHS.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's an equality of equivalence (congruence) *classes* but you are working with *representatives* of the classes.  The reps will be equal only if your *normalize* them to a canonical rep from each class (e.g. least nonnegative).

Comment: $0 \mod 10$ is not equivalent to $10 \mod 10$???  You have $10 \mod 10$ on both sides.  You've done everything right and you reached the conclusion you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mod 10$ is *not* the remainder function.  $3 \mod 10$ does not equal the number $3$ and $3$ exactly.

$3 \pmod {10}$ means $3$ is a representative of *any* of the infinite numbers that are equivalent to $3$.  (That is any one of $.....-17, -7,3,13, 23.....$etc.)  And we aren't saying anything about *specific* numbers.  We are saying things what classes of infinite numbers all have in common and who they relate.

If you have a number that is in the class $3$ represents.  (Let's say the number $-2,317$) And you have a number in the class that $7$ represents.  (Let's say $5,892,407$) and you add them together then the sum is going to be in the same class that $3+7$ is in.

And indeed $-2,317 + 5,892,407= 5,890,090$ and both $5,890,090$ and $10$ are both in the class $\{....., -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30,....\}$.  That is the class represent by $0$.  (ALthough it could just as easily have bee represented by $10$, or by $20$, or $-130$. or....)

That is what the statement $3\pmod {10} + 7 \pmod {10} \equiv (3+7) \pmod {10}$  means.

Also notice that that is not an equal sign with two stripes; it is an equivalence sign with three stripes.

When we do modular arithmetic we can think of what we are doing it two equivalent ways:

1) (a bit abstract).  We are doing math on entire *classes* of integers and $3$ is the set $\{...-17,-7, 3,13...\}$ and $7$ is the set $\{....-13,-3, 7,17,....\}$ and $3 + 7$ is an operation which is "set addition" where $\{...-17,-7, 3,13...\}+\{....-13,-3, 7,17,....\}= \{....., -20,-10,0,10,20...\}$ which is represented by $0$.

2) $\equiv$ is not $=$.  The statement $3 + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$ is not saying anything about what $3+7$ or what $0$ is.  It is saying $3+7=10$ and $0$ both belong in the same equivalence class.

Comment: Both $\ 3\mod 10\ $ and $\ 3\pmod{\!10}\ $ are major abuses of notation, and such abuse often confuses many beginners. One should avoid using it when attempting to clarify such matters.

Comment: @OP see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121054/242) for the difference between the binary **operation** $\,a\bmod n\,$ vs. ternary **relation** $\,a \equiv b\pmod{n}\,$ of congruence (an equivalence relation for *fixed* $n)\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply $\text{mod}(10)$ on both sides of any equation involving modular arithmetic.

Comment: but doesn't applying mod(10) for LHS give us 3 mod(10) + 7 mod(10) , which is just 3 + 7?

Comment: No. $3+7$ is a representative of $3+7 \mod (10).$ You could have also written $0 \mod (10)$ or $20\mod(10).$